# What kind of SSD interface does my laptop use?

Tags: laptop, ssd

I have a Toshiba E55t-A and I want to add an SSD. It has an empty area on the motherboard (even labeled SSD) but I want to be certain what interface it uses. Anyone have an idea?!

[image]

Comment: 1TB (5400 RPM) Serial ATA hard disk drive with 32GB (system use
only) solid state disk cache

Comment: Look like a soldered solution, but it's odd, I don't see enough connections for that to even be true

Comment: This is M.2. Notice that it says `JNGFF`—NGFF is the former name for M.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### This is an M.2 slot.

- **[M.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2)**, formerly Next Generation Form Factor (NGFF), is a new interface for internal expansion cards, especially SSDs. In addition to SATA, M.2 provides up to four **[PCI Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express)** lanes, allowing for nearly 4 GB/s of bandwidth with PCIe 3.0.
- The slot accepts **type 2242** cards. The more common type 2280 cards, typically used in desktops, are longer and will not fit.
- The tell-tale sign here is that the slot is marked `JNGFF`.